# How to recovery deleted system app by kingroot

Tags: stock-android

I accidentally deleted some bloatware apps in kingroot by rooting my device these were (Downloading manager,gallery etc.)

Now my smartphone is not working properly:

- My play store is not downloading any app.
- My browser is not downloading any thing.
- I have no gallery in it (I have installed a gallery.apk but it's no showing anything in it).
- When I go to my ringtone system the setting stops.
- There is no sound on incoming call (even if my volume is full).

Can I recovery or get back all deleted system apps? Please help me, I am very sad for two months.

Comment: This is the danger of root... You cannot undelete or recover this files on the device itself, you need to flash the factory ROM image to the device and return it to a known good state. The process varies by device.

Answer (score 1):

Open Kingroot, go to Purify. Click Tools at the bottom, then Bloatware Remover, then tap the little picture of a man and bin in the top right corner. This will allow you to undelete system apps. Cheers!

Comment: This should work, since the bloatware remover only freezes apps when you press "Uninstall" (to really remove it, you need to install another app).

Answer (score 0):

If you removed the apps, the best option to fix the problem is to flash back a normal stock ROM for your phone. (I don't know the model)